# Why googlebots not indexing phpbb3?

Tags: phpbb

I have used http://testuri.org/sniffer to check the content but found out that PHPBB3 serves a totally different content for example: http://codingforspeed.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=59

the google bots are not able to read them. So, how to make phpbb indexed by google? currently if I google site:http://codingforspeed.com/forum/    it only returns 1 index page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about search engine crawler indexing and doesn't involve any programming related problems. Webmasters might be a better place to ask this.

Comment: That sniffer page doesn't return content, it checks http response so won't show the page as a browser sees it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the solution, which is to manually add googlebot to phpbb

https://helloacm.com/how-to-fix-phpbb3-1-5-not-indexed-by-googlebots/